# How do I switch the keyboard layout so that the Apple key is CTRL and the ~ works correctly?

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, mac

How do I switch the keyboard layout in Ubuntu 11 so that the Apple key is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and the <kbd>~</kbd> works correct?

This is the specific keyboard I'm talking about:

[image]

When I hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>2</kbd> it returns a <kbd>"</kbd>

Comment: Do you also have errors when you try to type '@'?

Comment: Yep, Shift+2 = "

Comment: You already tried to change the layout under `System -> Preferences -> Keyboard`?

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways you can accomplish this task: The first way it GUI based, using:

```
Open Applications > System Tools > Configuration Editor
Then apps > metacity > global_keybindings in the tree view
```

This should enable you to modify your key values as long as you stay within the acceptable syntax.

The alternate way to edit your keybindings is by directly editing the gconf.xml files:

```
$HOME/.gconf/apps/metacity/gloabl-keybindings/%gconf.xml
$HOME/.gconf/apps/metacity/keybinding_commands/%gconf.xml
```

You can find more information at http://gnome-hacks.jodrell.net/hacks.html?id=14